# How to set image dimension pre-requisit upload into WPForms?

Tags: wordpress, customization, code-snippets, wpforms

I would like to know if there's some snippet or code for letting users upload images with certain dimension like 1200x1200 px

Answer (score 0):

I could manage this integrating a JS open source library named FilePond

https://pqina.nl/filepond/